# How can I edit embed with emoji buttons in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, edit

How can I edit embed with emoji buttons in discord.py?
I was making it like this.. but it doesn't works..

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!menu"):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF, title=f'Menu', description= f' - test1 \n - test2 \n - test3 \n - test4 \n - test5 \n - test6', timestamp=message.created_at)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'-', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('')await msg.reaction_add('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
```

```
if str(msg.add_reaction) == '':
            embed1=discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF, title=f'edit1', description= f'test1')
            await msg.edit(embed=embed1)
```

I want some edit codes!!

Comment: use `discord.ext.menus` for that, you can do that with the classic way, but it's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, you can use `discord.ext.menus`. Here's how you need to install it.

`pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus`.

Then you can do something like this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import menus

class ColorMenu(menus.Menu):
    def __init__(self, embed):
        super().__init__(timeout=30.0, delete_message_after=True)
        self.embed = embed
        self.result = None

   async def send_initial_message(self, ctx, channel):
       return await channel.send(embed=self.embed)

   @menus.button('')
   async def red_button(self, payload):
       # do what ever you want with this.
       # right now I'm going to just edit the message
       self.embed.description = 'test1'
       self.embed.title = 'title1'
       self.message.edit(embed=self.embed)

   # do the same thing for other reactions
```

Then make a new command and instantiate the class, like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def menu(ctx):
    color_menu = ColorMenu()
    color_menu.start(ctx)
```

And you're done.

Good luck with your bot.